# Map AudioClip data to pixels of Array from GetRawTextureData?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, render-to-texture

[`GetRawTextureData()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) returns a linear (one dimensional) array of all the pixels in a texture.

AudioClips contain interleaved (left and right) data, in a one dimensional array, such that indices represent the x (or time) and each value is either the left and right signal's volume at that x/time.  Even numbers = left and odd = right.

Is there a simple way to map this into the NativeArray that comes back from `GetRawTextureData()`

What I've tried, only focusing on showing the left signal, but is producing odd vertical results:

```
void FillTextureOne (Texture2D wav_tex, float[] firstWave ) {
    var texdata = wav_tex.GetRawTextureData<Color32>( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < firstWave.Length ; i+=2 )
    {
        var positionnew =  i/2 * 256  + ( firstWave[i] + 1 ) * 128 ;
        texdata[( int )positionnew ] = black;
    }
    wav_tex.Apply( );
}
```

texture is 256 x 256 in size. Array of AudioClip data has a length of 512, wherein stored values ranging from -1 to 1, and are being multiplied by 128 after adding one, in a failed attempt to range them between 0 and 256 vertically.

Comment: I don't know how this works, but x + (y * width) gets the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the solution you are confused about, here is a short explanation as to why it works. To properly map a 2D array into a 1D array, you would need to take the `width` and `height` of the 2D array, then take their product to give you the proper size of your 1D array. The next step is to make sure your 2D array is in [`row order or column order`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) which would decide how you access your information. Once that is figured out, there are two equations that will allow you to access a 1D array in the format of a 2D array using its width and height rather than a singular index. For simplicity, I will use your indexers `x` and `y` again along with `width` and `height`.

**For Row Order Arrays**

```
yourOneDimensionalArray[width * x + y]
```

**For Column Order Arrays**

```
yourOneDimensionalArray[height * y + x]
```

Think of a 1D array as a potential 2D array if you break it into equal sections. Depending on the order of your matrix, it will either define the row or column length based on either how large the break is or how many portions you can break apart.

A more visual explanation:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 is a 1D array of size 1x9

1 2 3
4 5 6 is a 2D array row order of size 3x3
7 8 9

1 4 7 
2 5 8 is a 2D array column order of size 3x3
3 6 9

If we want to access the number 6 in these arrays, we would do as follows:
1DArray[5]
2DRowArray[1][2]
2DColumnArray[2][1]

From the previous equations, we can now take the indexes we have to see how they relate.

2DRowArray is row 1, column 2 or x = 1, y = 2 and our width is 3, so we take 1 * 3 + 2, which is 3 + 2 = 5 or our 1D index

Similarly, the 2DColumnArray is row 2, column 1 or x = 2, y = 1 and our height is 3, so we take 1 * 3 + 2, which is 3 + 2 = 5 or our 1D index.
```

I could expand this visual solution to a `256x256` grid, but I think the `3x3` should get the idea across just as well. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: is y * width + x only working for me because the grid is square?

Comment: @Confused Nope! You can map a non-square 2D array to a 1D array as well. In my example, just take away the bottom row, and the way to find 6 still results in the same answer. Similarly, take away the last column in the column matrix and you'll get the same answer.

Comment: Think of it as a building and you're trying to find a room on a specific floor from the elevator - Room X on the floor Y, this is a 2D array. Now, imagine if all of these stacked floors have become a single long building. Instead of going up Y floors, you would now just go over Y floors, then still find your X. However, as there are no floors now but you know the previous height and what floor you wanted, you can still find the exact X or room you need by taking the height * Y + X.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to ask is this: you're suggesting width * x or height * y, yet I've got y * width working. If my texture is a non-square (eg 256 x 90), I think it shouldn't work the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Didn't mean to confuse you. The reason there are two equations depends on how the 2D array is packed. I believe most 2D arrays are row order, so yes, the current equation you are working most likely would not work with a non-square using the function you are using. To be sure, if you can pass in a non-square texture and see if it goes out of bounds you'll know.

Comment: Cheers! Will get around to that, I've just been battling with pointers and IntPtrs for a day or two, trying to get an optimised memcpy working to feed this, amongst other things.

Comment: @Confused Anytime! And gotcha sounds like a headache. Good luck! One other note. To clarify the X/Y/etc., `width * row + col` is row order while `height * col + row` is column order. The order is dependent on how you access the information from the array.

Comment: No worries. I'm making pointed progress: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034124/memcpy-nativearray-index-to-nativearray-index-of-length-how-to-do, but am permanently...

Answer (score 0):

In a real-time app, synchronizing commands (transfer pixel) unnecessarily reduces parallelism between the CPU and GPU. Unfortunally you haven't provided any information about your target device and os. If you want to achieve the maximum perfomance you should use [compute shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ComputeShader.html).

Comment: These are calculated sine, saw, triangle and square waves being drawn as samples of up to 1024 indexed samples each, before or after being used by the 'OnAudioFilterRead' feature of Unity. Is there a way to do all of this curve calculation as compute shaders AND efficiently get the final arrays to `OnAudioFilterRead`??

Comment: Yes, it all can be done with compute shaders.

Comment: I don't see how the final curve to CPU and RAM can be done efficiently to serve `OnAudioFilterRead`, from compute. It's the reverse problem of here, where there's a blit to GPU, via `Apply` - which is quite efficient in this case, because it's done once for all changes.