# memcpy NativeArray Index to NativeArray Index, of Length, how to do?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, memcpy, unsafe

NativeArrays in Unity don't have a partial copy feature from one to another.

There's various ways around this (NativeSlices and GetSubArray) but the ideal would be a zero checks, all trust, memcpy.

However, the closest I can conceive of is this, and it does nothing;

```
using Unity.Collections ;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe ;

namespace Unity.Collections {
  public static class NativeArrayExtensions {
    public static unsafe void CopySuperFast <T> (
      this NativeArray<T> src, int srcIndex,
      NativeArray<T> dst, int dstIndex,
      int length ) where T : struct {
      
      GCHandle dstHandle = GCHandle.Alloc ( dst, GCHandleType.Pinned ) ;
      GCHandle srcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc ( src, GCHandleType.Pinned ) ;
      UnsafeUtility.MemCpy ( 
                            ( void* ) ( dstHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject (  )
                                      + dstIndex * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) ), 
                             ( void* ) (  srcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject ( ) 
                                       + srcIndex * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) ), 
                            length ) ;
      dstHandle.Free (  );
      srcHandle.Free (  ) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `NativeSlice` is such a problem? Why would you want zero checks?

Comment: @Charlieface this is for a synthesizer. I'm doing all the monitoring of signal buffer needs and have, therefore done all the checks as part of the process of determining the portions of chunks required by the buffers. There's no longer any need for checks. As to Slice's problems, it's slower, by a good margin, than just a straight memcpy, as it's using checks and stride. There's no way to use it without checks and stride. SubArray is the fastest current option, but also much redundancy, and slower than an idealised memcpy without checks.

Comment: The faster, leaner and more efficiently this can be done, the more sounds, sound processing and effects can then be added, leading to more sound dynamics, better sounds and more fun. Hence the desire to find the best and fastest ways to do it.

Comment: I think my biggest problem is turning an index position indicator (`dstIndex` and `srcIndex`) and their accompanying size of each storage requirement of the type into a `void*` pointer. I'm not sure how to turn an `int` into a pointer relevant increasing type, let alone a type's length.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this answers your question but I can not format this properly as a comment.

```
namespace Unity.Collections
{
    public static class NativeArrayExtensions
    {
        public static unsafe void CopySuperFast<T>(
          this NativeArray<T> src, int srcIndex,
               NativeArray<T> dst, int dstIndex,
          int length
          ) where T : unmanaged
        {
            T* srcPtr = (T*)NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks(src);
            {
                var d = dst.GetUnsafePtr();
                UnsafeUtility.MemCpy(d, srcPtr + dstIndex, sizeof(T) * length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet is untested and I am not sure if it will work. More leaving it here as a jumping-off point for you to potentially figure it out.

Comment: You've jumped a few decades in front of my understanding of things. Why use unmanaged? What is this compared to the use of Struct? Sorry, ignorance is a close friend of mine.

Comment: `GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks` And how did you find this gem?

Comment: I can't any variation of this unmanaged idea to do anything. It might be changing memory way out west (or east) but it's not seemingly doing anything were the destination is located.

Comment: The example was Frankensteined from the post I linked and various functions I came across in the docs. For specifics as to why I used anything lies in the docs pages. Would link them but on mobile so its a bit of a pain.

Comment: Bit of a joker. If you'd like to take a look can link the [`main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.transport@0.2/api/Unity.Networking.Transport.LowLevel.Unsafe.DataStreamUnsafeUtility.html) doc

Comment: What? What is this documentation tunnel you're down. I've been reading from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks.html

Comment: It takes a bit of time to navigate unity docs. The doc I linked is the header doc to the one you linked.

Comment: Sorry. I should probably know what that means, or be able to find what it means. But i can't do either. It taps out at low level stuff that never gets off to the networking docs in your link.

Comment: @Confused Sorry you're was on mobile when I linked it. For whatever reason, the `Class DataStreamUnsafeUtility` is set under `Networking`. I found the page by looking into unsafe buffers and found the page. It should give some descriptions of functions like `GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks`, which I thought was useful.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED: Added second way based on @TEEBQNE's suggestions and ideas**

I've got the following working, but it might not be at all optimal in how it transfers void* to IntPtrs to do the math, and then has to go back to a (void*) pointer at the end:

```
    using Unity.Collections ;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe ;

namespace Unity.Collections {
  public static class NativeArrayExtensions {
    public static unsafe void CopySuperFast <T> (
      this NativeArray<T> src, int srcIndex,
           NativeArray<T> dst, int dstIndex,
      int length 
      ) where T : struct {
      UnsafeUtility.MemCpy ( 
                            destination : ( void* ) ( ( IntPtr ) dst.GetUnsafePtr ( ) 
                                       + dstIndex * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) ), 
                             source :     ( void* ) ( ( IntPtr ) src.GetUnsafePtr ( ) 
                                       + srcIndex * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) ),
                             size :       length * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) 
                                          ) ;
    }
    // a second idea, based on TEEBQNE's suggestions
    public static unsafe void CopySuperFastWithoutChecks <T> (
      this NativeArray<T> src, int srcIndex,
           NativeArray<T> dst, int dstIndex,
      int length 
      ) 
      where T : unmanaged 
    { 
      var size_T = UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T> ( ) ; 
      var srcPtr = (IntPtr)NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks ( src ) ; 
      var dstPtr = (IntPtr)NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks ( dst ) ;
      
      UnsafeUtility.MemCpy ( 
                            destination :( void* ) ( dstPtr + dstIndex * size_T), 
                            source :     ( void* ) ( srcPtr + srcIndex * size_T ), 
                            size :       length * size_T 
                                         ) ; 
  } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You might have already stumbled across this [`Unity post`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-there-a-utility-method-for-faster-copying-of-nativearray.543888/), but decided to drop it here just in case. The last post is similar to what you are trying to achieve but is taking a range of a managed array and using `MemCpy` to a NativeArray.

Comment: I barely understand what I've done, and gleaned it from a Stackoverflow post about C pointers and longs, and another post about how GCHandle was a waste of time. This forum post... I don't really understand what he's doing at the end. It seems more efficient than what I'm doing. Will read, and stare into the abyss for a while.

Comment: Nope, don't understand it. He's seemingly got a srcPtr from out of thin air. Unless this is something innate to ... no... I can't really follow what's going on in that final post. Does it make sense to you how it works?

Comment: From what I understand, it is because the inputted array is a managed array. When it comes down to it, arrays are just pointers, so I believe that is how the conversion can be made on the line `fixed (T * srcPtr = array)`. Specifically while using using the [`fixed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) keyword. Seems the post would not be of much help to you as I understand it as `NativeArray` can not be used with `fixed`.